# ubuntu server performance very slow while connecting with vnc viewer

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access, ibm

We have IBM X31000 server and using Ubuntu 14.04 amd64 os. the server performance going very slow while connecting with VNC viewer or other remote desktop application.

Please help us how to resolve the problem